# Characterizations of Euclidean space

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

There are presumably three ways of characterizing the abstract Euclidean space $E^n$ that are quite different in spirit:

1. axiomatically (with axioms concerning dimension)
2. by the abstract Euclidean group $E(n)$ (as its symmetry group, determining $E^n$ uniquely)
3. by presupposing a metric and requiring *that the space is a maximal one with respect to the property* that the $(n+1)$-dimensional [Cayley-Menger determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Menger_determinant) vanishes for all $(n+2)$-tuples of points *and does not vanish for all $k$-tuples of points "in general position" for $k < n+2$*.

<sup>[Having tried to "rescue" 3 by adding *conditions in italics*, due to Robin's comment.]</sup>

> **Question 1:** Is it correct, actually, that $E^n$ is uniquely
>   determined via 2 and 3?
>
> **Question 2:** What are other ways of
>   characterizing $E^n$ that are quite different in spirit?

Comment: The hypothesis in 3 holds for all **subsets** of $n$-dimensional Euclidean space, so it is inadequate by itself......

Comment: Now posted also on MathOverflow: [Characterizations of Euclidean space](https://mathoverflow.net/q/47882)

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. For instance, what does "general position" mean for general metric spaces? What  do you mean by (2)? Do you mean that it's isometry group is isomorphic to E(n)? Then there are other metric spaces with this property.